# How do I properly select part of an object to separate?

Tags: mesh, objects, selection-tools

I am trying to separate the highlighted area from this object. I have pressed <kbd>B</kbd> and then <kbd>P</kbd> to separate which works to an extent but it does not separate the whole area. I have rotated the object in the second picture. You can clearly see that only one side of this area has been selected. I basically tried to fix this by 'coloring in' the section by constantly pressing <kbd>B</kbd> and drawing little boxes over the black areas however, my molecules still look really patchy when I drag it away from its natural position and the framework underneath the molecules were also not selected.
 [image]

Comment: Your screen shots are unreadable. It would help to keep them full size.

Comment: Another quick way (if geometry to be selected is connected) is to select one or more vertices and press Ctrl+L to select the rest of the mesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to select *all* the vertices in part of a dense mesh, is to switch to wireframe shading (simply press <kbd>Z</kbd> or from the 3D view header *Viewport Shading* > *Wireframe*) then use a selection tool like border select, to select the region of interest.

The same can be accomplished in solid view by turning off *Limit Selection to Visible*.
[image: Limit Selection to Visible button in the 3D view header]

With either method  (wireframe or Limit Selection to Visible) you have disabled the depth culling on the selection, so you can select *all* the geometry, even the pieces "hiding" behind others.

With the piece selected the way you want then it is a simple matter to separate it <kbd>P</kbd> > *Selection*.